# Launching Gradle builds from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle

We're looking at converting our Ant build to Gradle.

In regards to integration with Eclipse, we are looking for (conceptually) equivalent functionality for launching builds from the IDE.  Eclipse provides a nice Ant view for invoking Ant targets.

There is an Eclipse plugin for launching Gradle builds (http://www.breskeby.com/downloads/gradle/eclipse/update/), but this seems to require users to jump through hoops to invoke different targets (edit the launch configuration, etc.).

How are others using Gradle from inside Eclipse?

Comment: This is how I am doing it: https://github.com/djangofan/WebDriverTestingTemplate

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The short answer is that we do not invoke gradle scripts from Eclipse.

I believe [this site](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GRADLE/Running+Gradle+from+Eclipse) outlines where this work is at the moment and it does not seem to be much right now.

I am a bit curious what kind of tasks you want to run from Eclipse. Why not run tasks from the command line?

Comment: Agreed, that plugin seems to be stalled.  Our development team is accustomed to invoking various Ant targets (clean, build, deploy, unit test, etc.) from the Eclipse Ant Viewer, and we're aiming for a conceptually seamless transition to Gradle.  With development being on Windows machines, there isn't much of a command prompt to speak of...

Comment: @csl: most of our team develops on windows as well and there is no problem with using gradle in the command prompt. I suggest you place this 'requirement' low. I would hate to see someone not transitioning from ant to gradle for this reason. All these features will be coming one day, if you have a chance, you should make the switch now :)

Comment: thanks, will give the command prompt a try.  It also looks like the Spring Tool Suite (http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?110617-STS-2.7.0.M2-released) has support for Gradle.

Comment: Hi, I am the author of the experimental Gradle plugin listed on the link you mentioned. You're right, I've stopped investing time in this eclipse plugin as the springsource sts guys start working on a plugin. the sts 2.7.2 has pretty nice gradle support. the functionality of my plugin is completely available in the sts plugin. but the functionality of the sts gradle plugin goes far beyond. Actually I am joining forces with them to get better Editor support for gradle files. This editor support is based on the new DSLD feature of the groovy-eclipse plugin.

Comment: @Rene: It's good to hear, that the development continues in that project! But does it mean I will have to use STS (which doesn't make much sense for me, as I'm not using Spring), or can I also install this as an Eclipse plugin/feature?

Comment: Hi chris, sorry for the delay. unfortunately you're right and have to use the sts platform. you can update your existing eclipse installation to get all you need. I've asked Andrew (Eisenberg) about providing that gradle support standalone, but that's actually not on their agenda. sorry.

Comment: There are so many reasons to want to use gradle from Eclipse. I think the right question would be why would you want to go to a separate command window to invoke Gradle. With my current Ant setup I can use a hotkey to auto-run my last Ant Target which is very convenient

Comment: Context switching is disruptive and therefore bad.  If you are already in the command line, that's fine.  Personally, I develop in Eclipse and I expect to be able to build right from Eclipse.  If that isn't supported, I am better served by tools that don't force me out of Eclipse for what I consider to be basic operations.

Answer (score 27):

This is kind of an old post, but the SpringSource STS team has released a plugin: http://static.springsource.org/sts/docs/latest/reference/html/gradle/

Installation instructions can be found here:  http://static.springsource.org/sts/docs/latest/reference/html/gradle/installation.html

My experience has been pretty positive with it so far.  For straight-up Java projects it works quite well.  I am having some issues generating correct war files through Eclipse, while using the Gradle plugin, but gradle itself does it wonderfully.  I am relatively new to gradle and the plugin though, so it could be something that I am missing.

[image]

Comment: It is pretty easy to install the Spring Gradle Tooling plugin in Eclipse Juno.  Just add the regular Juno software repo site to you install sources, install the "marketplace" app, restart Eclipse, then use the marketplace app to install Gradle and/or Groovy.

Comment: On a side note, I have been using IntelliJ for the last year or so and the Gradle integration is wonderful!!

Comment: Personally, I think the "run-as" dialogues for IntelliJ are harder to understand in terms of Gradle.  Its hard for me to explain, but I think Eclipse is much easier in that respect.

Comment: @djangofan it would be interesting to hear your experience with IntelliJ 13 - with the much improved gradle integration.  I can't go back to Eclipse :P

Comment: i understand.  the Eclipse Gradle plugin is still based off Gradle 1.6 anyways.

Comment: Building on this, I had a need to run multiple gradle commands in parallel. I was able to accomplish this by creating an Eclipse launcher of type Launch Group. Then when you hit add, you can select from Gradle Build commands (if you've run them at least once before from the STS Gradle Tasks shown in this answer). This can be used for a single Gradle command if preferred in the Run Configurations dropdown.

Comment: Installing STS Gradle now results in a popup saying that it is under minimal maintenance and a link to how to migrate to Buildship.

Answer (score 25):

Interim work-around more palatable to those with command-line phobia.

From Eclipse, use pulldown menu Run / External Tools / External Tools Configurations...

Select "Program" in left navigator panel then click the "New launch configuration" button in the tool bar (first button in my tool bar).

With Main tab selected, fill out the following fields:

1. Name: (above the tabs) to "Gradle" (or whatever name you want for the launcher).
2. Location:  Use "Browse File System..." button to navigate to your "gradle.bat" or "gradlew.bat" to run.
3. Working Directory:  Use "Browse Workspace..." button to select directory with the "build.gradle" file for the desired project.
4. Arguments:  Enter "--gui"

Add to Arguments: the switch "-b filename.gradle" if you use a Gradle build file other than "build.gradle".

After this, your developers can use the Run / External Tools or tool bar button to launch the Gradle Gui.  They can do this and close it after each use, or (to avoid startup lag), minimize it when not in use.

Comment: This is a perfectly acceptable solution as well and the general way to run external tools from Eclipse w/o explicit support.  I still don't see what problem the OP has with running commands from a seperate terminal though.  It's prolly faster anyway.

Comment: agree with omnisis:  I don't see this as an "interim workaround" at all.  Note that, instead of running in gui mode, you can simply call gradle (or gradlew) passing "build" or "run".  You can have any of these run configs display in the External Tools dropdown menu for quick access.

Comment: Agree with the above comments... the whole point of a build tool is to reduce sometimes very complex tasks as far as is humanly possible to one or two simple commands, such as "gradle build" or "gradle testCompile" or whatever!  Arguably if your gradle command is very long with lots of parameters and switches, AND you keep repeating it, although it is the case with both Linux terminal and the Windows DOS thingy that it is trivial to repeat a command, you should probably find a simple CLI way of not having to enter a long command (e.g. a new Task or gradle.properties)

Answer (score 11):

The current answer to this question should be, 
Use Gradle's own Eclipse plugin **Buildship**:

http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship

This is supported and developed by the Gradle team and will be continuously improved in the future. It can also handle older versions (with functionality based on Gradle version availability).

Edit 2017-03-01:
After the release of Buildship 2.0, the integration is even better and I recommend it (unless your already using IntelliJ, then your already set).
There are still some features missing like the ability to directly debug JavaExec tasks and the ability to run precompile/preimport tasks, but those are in their [Github issues list](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues).

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old question, but I still do not think it is possible to have Eclipse run a gradle build for you.  The Spring Gradle plugin is a great start, if you use that, you can define an external tool builder to run gradle when you want.  If you have lots of projects and all are being built with gradle, you can even have gradle add the capability to your eclipse projects for you.  While this can be cleaned up, you can add something like this to your gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

eclipse {
    project {
        // Store a copy of the desired Gradle_Builder.launch file in a top-level 'master'
        //    directory.  Then this code searches for it, and by copying it, 
        //    adds the launch file to the specifc project that will run gradle
        String launchFileNameOrig = '.externalToolBuilders/Gradle_Builder.launch'
        String launchFileName = launchFileNameOrig
        File launchFile = file(launchFileName)
        boolean needToCopy = false
        while (!launchFile.exists()) {
            launchFileName = '../' + launchFileName
            launchFile = file(launchFileName)
            needToCopy = true
        }
        if (needToCopy) {
             copy {
                from (launchFile)
                into '.externalToolBuilders'
            }
        }

        buildCommand 'org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder', LaunchConfigHandle: '<project>/'+launchFileNameOrig
        file {
            // when they made the "buildCommand" it looks like they left off 'triggers', so parse the XML until
            // the right place is found, then insert it.
            withXml {
                def projectNode = it.asNode()
                projectNode.iterator().each { subNode ->
                    String subNodeText = '' + subNode
                    if (subNodeText.startsWith('buildSpec')) {
                        subNode.iterator().each { buildCmd ->
                            String nameNode = buildCmd?.name
                            if (nameNode.contains('ExternalToolBuilder')) {
                                buildCmd.appendNode('triggers', 'full')
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the content of the file stored at the top of the directory hierarchy under: ./.externalToolBuilders/Gradle_Builder.launch.   As defined here, this will only run after a "clean"  [Gradle is more expensive time-wise than the native Java Builder, so continue to use that for auto-building].   Note: the file contents below also assumes that you are using "git" and the gradle wrapper.  You see this on the ATTR_LOCATION value.  Adjust as needed.  One nice thing about this approach though is that you can have the gradle wrapper be any version of gradle you want, and then eclipse will use that version when it runs!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ProgramBuilderLaunchConfigurationType">
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.ATTR_REFRESH_SCOPE" value="${workspace}"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.ui.ATTR_LAUNCH_IN_BACKGROUND" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_LOCATION" value="${git_dir}/../gradlew"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_RUN_BUILD_KINDS" value="full,"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_TOOL_ARGUMENTS" value="assemble"/>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_TRIGGERS_CONFIGURED" value="true"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ATTR_WORKING_DIRECTORY" value="${project_loc}"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom launcher from eclipse which would invoke your Gradle build.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Gradle Eclipse plugin](http://www.gradle.org/eclipse_plugin.html) like `gradle eclipse` to generate an Eclipse project from the gradle project. It adds a lot of targets to the generated Eclipse projects and is highly customizable.

Comment: Thanks, but the question was around invoking Gradle from Eclipse - not generating Eclipse projects.

Answer (score 2):

As ever, you are better off with IDEA.
Support has been around since 2009 http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/08/gradle-support/

and even fuller support is available now via the EAP (free to use!)
http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/09/keen-to-try-gradle-integration-in-intellij-idea/

Comment: You are just right. I wish my team was not retarded and use IDEA. But they anyway hold to Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Buildship](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship) as stated by FkYkko. However, one thing to keep in mind is that Ant tasks are considered first-class citizens in gradle. This means you can simply import an ant build script, referencing its tasks the same way you reference gradle tasks. Doing things this way allows you to simply use your ant tasks out of the box with gradle, without converting them to gradle tasks.

For example, say you have a build script named build.xml in the same directory as your build.gradle, and a task in build.xml named buildProj. You can import build.xml, and call build proj from build.gradle like this:

```
task antDeps {
    ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
}

task buildAll (dependsOn:['buildProj']) {
    // the rest of your gradle task here.
}
```

See [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#N10CBD), or [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html#sec:import_ant_build) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

There is also Enide Gradle http://www.nodeclipse.org/projects/gradle
that can be used with or without Gradle IDE by Pivotal.
In Gradle, Maven or CDT(C++) project.

[image: run]

As separate plugin, it can have different configuration for Gradle version and Java version to use

[image]

This, Gradle IDE Pack are within [Enide](http://www.nodeclipse.org/enide/2015/)

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question after installing the newer Buildship plugin which is phasing out Spring Tool Suite mentioned by others here.

Instructions for using task view with Buildship are as follows:

> **Using the Gradle Tasks view**
>
> After successfully importing a Gradle project, the project is shown in
>   the Gradle Tasks view.
>   [image]
>   By right clicking on a certain Gradle task in the Gradle Tasks view, you can run the selected Gradle task.
>
> [image]
>
> By default the result is displayed in the Gradle Executions view. It
>   is also displayed in the Console view similar to the output you would
>   get if you run the task via the command line.

[Source](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html#using-the-gradle-tasks-view-2)

Answer (score 1):

One more new project in 2016 is EGradle
[image]

https://github.com/de-jcup/egradle

Also does not require Project to be of particular nature, just existing `build.gradle` would be enough.

User guide is in built-in help (<kbd>F1</kbd>) or preview at https://rawgit.com/de-jcup/egradle/master/egradle-plugin-main/html/user_guide.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Gradle Eclipse plugin like gradle eclipse to generate an Eclipse project from the gradle project. It adds a lot of targets to the generated Eclipse projects and is highly customizable.