# Gradle Exception On multproject Dependency JAVA

Tags: java, gradle

- > Module version lotto:lotto.api:1.0, configuration 'testRuntime' declares a
  dependency on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the module descri
  ptor for lotto.api:InsicWebService2:unspecified*

I get this error msg while run gradle cleaneclipse eclipse

My project A bild.gradle

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: "maven"

group = "aa"
version = 1.0

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

}

jar {
    from configurations.runtime
}
```

My Project B depend on A build .gradle

```
dependencies {

    compile     project(':InsicWebService2')
    runtime     project(":InsicWebService2")
```

And setting .gradle on project B
includeFlat "ProjectA"

project A build sucessfully but error comes on project B

Comment: Once you create the gradle project run the command to create default files for gradle by `gradle eclipse` also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442619/launching-gradle-builds-from-eclipse for more details

Comment: Thanks @Raghuveer for quick reply.. Yes i did but now I get ClassNotFound Exception on A class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017364/how-to-create-java-gradle-project should help you  :) and if something is not found then it only means that dependency is not added yet.