# How to configure Eclipse with Gradle in multi project?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I'm using Eclipse Mars, Buildship plugin, JDK 1.8 and Gradle 2.9 on OS X

I need below structure in Eclipse. How to configure and create?

```
my-examples/
    settings.gradle
    01_example/
        build.gradle
        src/main/java
        src/main/resources
        src/test/java
        src/test/resources
    02_example/
        build.gradle
        src/main/java
        src/main/resources
        src/test/java
        src/test/resources
    03_example/
        build.gradle
        src/main/java
        src/main/resources
        src/test/java
        src/test/resources
```

The root directory `my-examples` is just wraps sub directories(`01_example`, `02_example`, `03_example`).

---

Here is `build.gradle` in root directory I tried to configure:

```
subprojects {
   apply plugin: 'java'
   sourceCompatibility = 1.8
   targetCompatibility = 1.8
   repositories {
       jcenter()
   }
   task initSourceFolders {
       sourceSets*.java.srcDirs*.each { it.mkdirs() }
       sourceSets*.resources.srcDirs*.each { it.mkdirs() }
   }
}
```

---

Edited

First, I created a directory and created `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` with `include exam1`, `include exam2`, and `include exam3`.
Now I imported the project from Gradle Project. The sub directories has been created that I needed.

**But** problem is that I can't create another sub directory in Eclipse and it's same in shell `mkdir exam4` and `gradle build`. Always It has been created normal folder.

[Project workspace in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR74b.png)

Comment: With Maven, I would try to "Import existing Maven projects", which would create appropriate "views" of every subproject adjacent to the parent project.  This way, Eclipse would show you the flat multiproject structure it likes, offering you proper java projects based on each Maven module configuration.  I don't know if this is feasible with Gradle, however :(

Comment: A few days ago, I have found a solution.

Comment: @demavend Whats the solution you found ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install Gradle plugin for eclipse from here:

"https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/blob/master/README.md"

Installation steps are given here: 
"https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/blob/master/README.md#installation-instructions".

You can view the following post for further information:

"[Launching Gradle builds from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442619/launching-gradle-builds-from-eclipse)".

Comment: What is differences between Buildship and eclipse integration gradle? I used all, but now buildship.

Comment: BuildShip is nothing but the collection of different plugins that are used to integrate Gradle into Eclipse so that building projects become easier.

Comment: I believe the Gradle plugin is available in the Eclipse Marketplace as a one-button install.

Comment: buildship does not support multi project, nor do they plan to. smart decisions.. :)